# WP Debug enabled Undefined index error in a widget

Tags: php, functions, widgets, errors, validation

I have set WP debug to true, and I am getting error message →

> Notice: Undefined index: tick_the_snippet_type

```
<p>
    <input
        type="radio"
        <?php checked( $instance[ 'tick_the_snippet_type' ], 'tick_snippet_4' ); ?>
        id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tick_snippet_4' ); ?>"
        name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('tick_the_snippet_type'); ?>"
        value="tick_snippet_4"
    />
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tick_snippet_4' ); ?>">The Widget #3</label>
</p>
```

This is the line that is throwing the error →

```
<?php checked( $instance[ 'tick_the_snippet_type' ],
```

What is the Fix for this?

## The code update as requested →

```
public function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    $instance = $old_instance;  
    $instance['tick_the_snippet_type'] = $new_instance['tick_the_snippet_type'];
    return $instance;
}
```

Comment: Show the rest of your code. Where does the `$instance` come from?

Comment: Updated. Please let me know If additional input is needed.

Comment: and the rest of it? Especially constructor

Comment: I am driving way back to home and stuck in traffic. I will update it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use a value from an array, like `$array['key']` where it's possible that the `'key'` doesn't exist (such as the first time a widget is used) you need to check that it exists before using it or you'll get errors on those occasions where it hasn't been set.

Your problem is that when the widget's first added `'tick_the_snippet_type'` doesn't exist on `$instance`, so you need to account for this possibility. I'd suggest creating a variable to pass to `checked()` which will either contain `tick_the_snippet_type` or a default if it doesn't exist:

```
if ( isset( $instance['tick_the_snippet_type'] ) ) {
    $value = $instance['tick_the_snippet_type'];
} else {
    $value = false;
}
```

Which can be written on one line with a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
$value = isset( $instance['tick_the_snippet_type'] ) ? $instance['tick_the_snippet_type'] : false;
```

And then use this for checked:

```
<?php checked( $value, 'tick_snippet_4' ); ?>
```